# Calculate IP in IP range

Tags: vb.net, ip

I have IP range string below:

```
Dim IPRange as String = "192.168.0.1-192.168.0.100"
```

I used code to count IP and add into Arraylist:

```
Dim beginIP() As Byte = IPAddress.Parse(IPRange.Split("-")(0)).GetAddressBytes
Array.Reverse(beginIP)
Dim endIP() As Byte = IPAddress.Parse(IPRange.Split("-")(1)).GetAddressBytes
Array.Reverse(endIP)

Dim IPbegin As UInt32 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(beginIP, 0)
Dim IPend As UInt32 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(endIP, 0)
Dim total as Integer = 0
Dim arr as New ArrayList()

For i As UInt32 = IPbegin To IPend
   Dim IPbyte() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(i)
   Array.Reverse(IPbyte)
   Dim IPCheck As String = New IPAddress(IPbyte).ToString
   total += 1
   arr.Add(IPCheck)
Next
```

But I have thousand IPRange like that with billion IP, loop make my application very slow. How can I speed up this code or another way to calculate IP range in this case?

Comment: Use multithreading?

Comment: I ran the code and did not have an issue with thousands.  Millions were produced in under a second.  If there is an issue you aren't showing the code with the problem.

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList`, it's very old. Use a `List(Of T)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code

```
    Dim stpw As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew

    Dim IPRange As String = "192.168.0.0-192.200.255.255"
    Dim beginIP() As Byte = IPAddress.Parse(IPRange.Split("-"c)(0)).GetAddressBytes
    Array.Reverse(beginIP)
    Dim endIP() As Byte = IPAddress.Parse(IPRange.Split("-"c)(1)).GetAddressBytes
    Array.Reverse(endIP)

    Dim IPbegin As UInt32 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(beginIP, 0)
    Dim IPend As UInt32 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(endIP, 0)
    Dim total As Integer = 0

    For i As UInt32 = IPbegin To IPend
        Dim IPbyte() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(i)
        Array.Reverse(IPbyte)
        Dim IPCheck As String = New IPAddress(IPbyte).ToString
        total += 1
    Next

    stpw.Stop()
    Debug.WriteLine("{0:n0} in {1}", total, stpw.Elapsed)
```

with a larger range produced these results.

2,162,688 in 00:00:00.3756208